# How to include secondary drives' files into 'All My Files' feature

Tags: finder, ssd, folders

I have a dual drive setup (SSD as boot, HDD for storage in my Mac).
I would like to know how I can include files form my HDD into finders features like 'All My Files'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'All My Files' is a [Smart Folder](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4158), that is, a saved Spotlight search, named `myDocuments.cannedSearch`:

[image]

and located in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/MyLibraries`. You probably shouldn't modify it, as it is a system file.

However, you can create your own Smart Folder using 'All My Files' as a template:

1. Select 'All My Files' and click 'Show search criteria':

   [image]
2. Choose 'This Mac' to search the entire computer:

   [image]
3. Click Save and specify a name, for example 'All My Items Everywhere', and a location for your Smart Folder (the default in `~/Library/Saved Searches` should be OK).

   The Smart Folder will appear in the sidebar.
4. Select 'All My Items Everywhere', right click and arrange by kind:

   [image]

   to get a similar output as 'All My Items':

   [image]

The downside of creating your own Smart Folder is that you can't configure the Finder so that new windows display 'All My Items Everywhere'.