# Extending Finder view "All My Files" to external drives

Tags: macos, finder

Is there a way to include files on external drives in the Finder's "All My Files" view? I found [this older answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95288/how-to-include-secondary-drives-files-into-all-my-files-feature), but it's not working in OS X 10.10.

Comment: The linked solution works for me (running 10.10.3). Are the external drives excluded from Spotlight indexing?  Take a look at  `System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy`

Comment: How much of the process isn't working? (i.e. Where have you gotten to?)